# wordpress and asp.net togther

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, seo

I have asp.net web app and want to add WordPress into my website, I found 1 way to add WordPress into my asp.net page is by using iframe.

Question, if I add wordpress into iframe, does it have SEO downsides? please explain if it does, and also if anyone knows another way to add wordpress into an existing asp.net app, please share. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress is PHP.  Some servers can run multiple server languages.  If your server supports asp.net and PHP, you could simply install WordPress into a sub directory or sub domain:

`mysite.com/blog/` or `blog.mysite.com/`

I'd talk to your hosting service to determine the best way to do this, but it can't be that hard.  I wouldn't recommend putting it in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem is that your entire blog will be represented by one page/url. I would use a subdomain to host the blog. E.g. blog.domain.com